# How to remove or stub Facebook messages in rspec logs e.g, `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am seeing a lot of Facebook related notifications in my rspec outputs.

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://127.0.0.1:51202/ from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/page.php

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/bz-D0tzmBsw.js?version=42#channel=f2&origin=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5 from frame with URL about:blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I do not need these Facebook calls within my test suite, so what is the best way to disable them globally?

I tried stubbing these calls in rails_helper.rb

```
before :each do 
  stub_request(:get, /connect.facebook.net/).
    to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
  stub_request(:get, /staticxx.facebook.com/).
    to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
  stub_request(:get, /facebook.com\/v2.5\/plugins\/page/).
    to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
end
```

But this has not worked, and I am still seeing the above messages in rspec logs.

What is the best way to prevent these messages?